# How do I setup a Vulkan dev environment with CLion?

Tags: c++, cmake, development-environment, clion, vulkan

I have no idea how to setup a Vulkan environment with CLion, the tutorial uses Visual Studio, heres the link. How do I make cmake or clion locate vulkan?

https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment

Comment: The documentation also has a section how to setup a makefile project. For CLion you would have to create a CMake project. Not impossible, but probably some work to do, if they don't proivde a CMake setup. Knowing how to create a makefile setup, should provide the information you would need for a CMake project as well.

Comment: Cmake environments can be a bit difficult to set up but is a great skill to learn in the programming world.

Comment: `CLion` is just IDE (integrated development environment). Most probably when you installed it it was shipped with some compiler: gcc/MinGW/clang. Now the OS and compiler determines how to install libraries.

Answer (score 1):

This is the beauty of CMake and open source. Ideally CLion doesn't really impact this.

I'm going to link to my other more generic answer that doesn't involve CLion:
[How I setup Vulkan using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66585573/how-i-setup-vulkan-using-cmake/66585574#66585574)

That way once you go through that if there are still issues with CLion we can answer them here.